# What server specification are enough for 10,000 concurrent users requests on my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, server-side, digital-ocean, puma

I want to deploy my Rails 5 app on DigitalOcean 1GB standard droplets. I'm going to use  puma or puma + nginx. I hope there will be atleast 10,000 concurrent users requests on my website.

Is these server specification are enough for entertain these users without hang.

Also one thing i want to ask that user can create items. On each item user can attach image from 1-4.

I want my app super fast, so saving 4 images i need to go this process in background using delayed jobs or no need to go in background.

Thanks

Comment: For the images yes go for jobs on separated droplets. The rest is not easy to answer

Comment: too much information missing... capacity planning is a lot more than "how many concurrent users" and the size of a droplet. For starters, 10,000 concurrent users making one request per minute each is not the same as 10,000 concurrent users making 10 requests per minute each. And that's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Also, you should consider if 10,000 is represents peak or average traffic. Or is it what analytics tools measure as "using right now" which means they've hit the server in the last few minutes.

Comment: Consider the following questions (in addition to the missing information mentioned already): How long does is a single request take when the server has a single concurrent user? How many requests does that user make per minute / second? For example, if a single request takes 100ms, then a single thread might not be able to fit more than 10 requests per second. Using multiple workers also has it's limits if the CPU is shared.